# Deserialize JSON to custom class returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC application with two micro services. In the first I call `PostAsync()` method to send my custom object

```
public class Logo { 
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<byte> Content { get; set; } 
}
```

to another service

```
public async Task PostLogo(Logo logo)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            await client.PostAsync(_url, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logo), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
        }
    }
```

In the second micro service I try to deserialize using

```
[HttpPost, Route("logo")]
    public Task<FileUploadResultModel> SaveAsync([FromBody]Logo model)
    {            
        return _fileService.SaveAsync(null);
    }
```

but it gets null instead of input object

[image].

Can anyone explain how can I send/process custom object using Post request, please?

Comment: update action to `Task<FileUploadResultModel> SaveAsync([FromBody]OutlookLogo model)`. framework will deserialize for you and bind object model

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is 'null' in the input string, before actual deserialization. I mean the 'model' value is null, but if I check 'JsonConvert.SerializeObject(logo)' it returns actual result with necessary parameters. So I think I'm doing something wrong while sending the request?

Comment: It is the same but they are in different micro services. I've renamed the classes, but it is still null

Comment: In that case it is possible that the byte array is too large so the model binder is unable to properly bind the model.

Comment: Also if you are able to get the image smaller you should base64 Url encode that image to a string and sent that as the content.

Comment: It looks like you are absolutely right. If I try to send only Id, it works great. Many thanks for your help. Do you have any idea how to send an image in such case?

Comment: Check you web.config and see what is the max size of data that can be sent. You may need to increase it. The max is 2GB but I would advise against such a high value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update action to follow preferred syntax structure.

```
[HttpPost, Route("logo")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveAsync([FromBody]Logo model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        FileUploadResultModel result = await _fileService.SaveAsync(model);
        return Ok(result);
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Based on comments it is possible that the byte array is too large so the model binder is unable to properly bind the model. Check the *web.config* and see what is the max size of data that can be sent. You may need to increase it. The max is 2GB but I would advise against such a high value.

Check this answer: [Maximum request length exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853767/maximum-request-length-exceeded#3853785)

If you are able to get the image smaller you should base64 Url encode that image to a string and sent that as the content.

```
public class Logo { 
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public string Content { get; set; } 
}
```

And when you get the model convert the content back to a byte array

```
[HttpPost, Route("logo")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveAsync([FromBody]Logo model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        byte[] content = Convert.FromBase64String(model.Content);
        var id = model.Id;
        //...
        return Ok(result);
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```